Not able to show the posts on my react app, nothing is output
I am trying to make a blogging site using React while watching a tutorial but I am stuck to a point where the posts are not displaying on the screen.
github repo link-> https://github.com/AkshatGarg2005/blogging-site
code->
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Itaque eos, incidunt reiciendis dolorum cumque delectus natus iure commodi, asperiores iste tempore beatae modi sunt libero nobis adipisci dignissimos voluptatem. Atque.",
    img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/7008010/pexels-photo-7008010.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Itaque eos, incidunt reiciendis dolorum cumque delectus natus iure commodi, asperiores iste tempore beatae modi sunt libero nobis adipisci dignissimos voluptatem. Atque.",
    img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/6489663/pexels-photo-6489663.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Itaque eos, incidunt reiciendis dolorum cumque delectus natus iure commodi, asperiores iste tempore beatae modi sunt libero nobis adipisci dignissimos voluptatem. Atque.",
    img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4230630/pexels-photo-4230630.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Itaque eos, incidunt reiciendis dolorum cumque delectus natus iure commodi, asperiores iste tempore beatae modi sunt libero nobis adipisci dignissimos voluptatem. Atque.",
    img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/6157049/pexels-photo-6157049.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
  },
];

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="posts">
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <div className="post" key={post.id}>
            <div className="img">
              <img src={post.img} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
              <Link className="link" to={`/post/${post.id}`}>
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
              </Link>
              <p>{post.desc}</p>
              <button>Read More</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

The output I am getting is OUTPUT I AM GETTING
the output which should come is OUTPUT WHICH SHOULD COME

Please [edit] to share a complete and properly formatted and readable [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, including more complete details what the exact specific issue is, along with any error messages in full with any accompanying stacktraces, and any debugging details you may have already collected. See Help/How to Ask for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

I see ( in your GitHub ) that you have defined the Home component in the route /home.
So, I suspect that you are in the / route and you don't find the post there.
The Code for rendering the posts my mapping seems pretty correct. You need to check the routes and where you are rendering the home component. I used the same code and it renders the posts just fine. If the route is correct. You might need to share your console logs here as well for better clarity of the problem.
